# What's the simplest way to include the COUNT of associations in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, group-by

Say I have a **[Products]** table, and a **[Products.record]** can have many **[Sales.records]** associated with it.

I want to have a single dataset that gives me number of sales a product has. Of course a product can have zero sales.

The first version of my query looks like this:

```
SELECT products.*,COUNT(*) as num_of_sales
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id
```

The problem of course is that this query can't distinguish between Products that have had 1 sale and 0 sales.

So, how can I get this very simple dataset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

don't use `COUNT(*)` but instead, `COUNT(sales.product_id)`.

```
SELECT  products.*,
        COUNT(sales.product_id) as num_of_sales
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales 
            ON sales.product_id = products.id
GROUP   BY products.id
```

As a sidenote, you should specify all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: +1 thanks JW. In your sidenote comment, why is that? And, would it suffice to state GROUP BY products.* ?